# Binding Canvas Programmatically, Loading and Clearing them

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, binding, windows-store-apps

I am building an application like a noteBook in Landscape. 
I have two canvas next to each other and I'm changing the Background inside them.
Every time I write on the two canvas and move to another 2 backgrounds, I need to save what I wrote on the two canvas and reload it once I move to these backgrounds once again, and clear them. And do the same for all the backgrounds.

```
<Grid x:Name="RenderedGrid" Width="1140" Height="770">
      <ScrollViewer x:Name="DScrollViewer" MaxZoomFactor="2.0" MinZoomFactor="1.0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ZoomMode="Disabled">

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <Canvas x:Name="inkCanvas0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="570">
                           <Canvas.Background>
                               <ImageBrush x:Name="DImage0" ImageSource="{Binding}"/>
                           </Canvas.Background>
                       </Canvas>
                       <Canvas x:Name="inkCanvas1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="570">
                           <Canvas.Background>
                               <ImageBrush x:Name="DImage1" ImageSource="{Binding}"/>
                           </Canvas.Background>
                       </Canvas>
             </StackPanel>

       </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I need to bind the Canvas in a way to this class instead of inkCanvas0 & inkCanvas1:

```
    public class MyCanvas
    {
        public Canvas inkCanvas { get; set; }
    }

    List<MyCanvas> CanvasList = new List<MyCanvas>();
```

This is how I am creating Empty Canvas and storing them in CanvasList:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
        {
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
            canvas.Name = "inkCanvas" + i;

            MyCanvas mc = new MyCanvas();
            mc.inkCanvas = canvas;

            CanvasList.Add(mc);
        }
```

I need to Bind these Canvas to the its corresponding page (inkCanvas0 to page0)
but I'm getting an exception in Xaml when I try to bind the Name of the Canvas.

```
<Canvas x:Name="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="570">
```

**Exception: Catastrophic failure The name already exists in the tree.**

How can I solve this? Is my logic of creating and loading the Canvas correct?

Comment: you may need to rethink your Bindings ie `<Canvas x:Name="{Binding]">` looks like you are trying to bind the page to the string name of the Canvas which won't work.

Comment: How to bind the ink written on the canvas?